# load_model to evaulate a test data on already trained model gives very low accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have trained a model and saved it in .h5 format. when I used the same file, train the model, saved it and load it it gives good accuracy like 84%. But when I used code to only load the model and use it to evaluate on test data the accuracy is very low like 1.004%. I am unable to understand the reason behind it.

```
history=model.fit([x1, x2], y,
                  epochs=1,
                  batch_size=256,
                  shuffle = False,
                   verbose = 1,
                  validation_split=0.2,
                  class_weight=custom_weight_dict,
                  callbacks=[early_stopping_cb]
                  )
model.save('my_models/model_context1.h5')
```

Then I used following code to load the saved model and evaluate it on test data.

```
model=load_model("my_models/model_context1.h5")
print(model.summary())
score = model.evaluate([x1_test, x2_test], y_test)
print("Accuracy after loading Model:", score[1]*100)
```

What's the wrong with the way I am trying to evaluate a trained model accuracy on test data? and using  the saved .h5 file.

Comment: please show the code you used to save the model.

Comment: I have added the way I m storing the model using model.save command.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is due to the fact that if you used model.save by default it saves it in what they call the SavedModel format. This is different than the .h5 format.To save it in the .h5 format you pass save_format='h5 into model.save or pass it a filename that ends in .h5.
Documentation is [here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize).See the example. The SavedModel format is the preferred format so I would suggest you use that since eventually they will depreciate the .h5 format.

Comment: I used   ```model.save('my_models/model_context1.h5')``` and this is exactly what documentation says either save_format='h5' or pass a filename that ends with.h5.

Comment: yes it looks ok. How are you loading the test data? Are you using ImageDataGenerator? Are you sure you are presenting the data in exactly the same way for both the no train and retrain cases.?